# passport-google-oauth unable to logout user

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

I use the `passport-google-oauth` module to authenticate users on a web application I built using `Express.js`. The logout event is handled this way:

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    console.log("logged out!");
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

While this does redirect the user to the login page (at `/`), I'm not sure it really logs him out. After clicking on logout, when I open `Gmail` in a new tab, I remain logged in there (and no, I hadn't logged into `Gmail` earlier). How can I fix this? Also, what does `req.logout()` do to log the user out?

Comment: Please let me know for more detail

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is perfectly normal.
When a user logs in *to* your application *with* his Google Account, he also logs in *to* all Google Services.

`req.logout()` only destroys the session that was created by Passport when the user logged in. That session was only linked to your application, not to the entire user's Google Profile.

If you want to log out the user from his Google Account as well, you'll have to redirect him to `https://accounts.google.com/logout` via a click on a button or something like that.

But this is very a debated policy, because, if you were already logged in to gmail, YouTube etc..., you would be logged out from all Google services at the same time. Pretty annoying.

For more information, check out [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909332/how-to-logout-of-an-application-where-i-used-oauth2-to-login-with-google) by jmort253.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the session for google not expired for this u can use this one at google end.

```
// route for logging out
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.session.destroy(function(e){
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

it will destroy your session from app. but if you want complete logout even from google account you can redirect to

> https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?logout&hl=en

address