# How to sign out of gmail account?

Tags: java, android, authentication, gmail-api

I am using solution provided here  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android to authenticate using gmail, while it works fine when i logout, I am unable to figure out about how to sign out.

I have tried following

```
GoogleAuthUtil.clearToken(AuthMainActivity.this,mCredential.getToken());
```

But clearing token seems to be not helping.

Comment: Have you stumbled across [this great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909332/how-to-logout-of-an-application-where-i-used-oauth2-to-login-with-google)?

Comment: @Tholle thanks , i understood it perfectly :)