# How to sign out a user after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-signin

I'm following [Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#sign_out_a_user) to sign out a user.

Considering that `gapi.auth2` will be undefined after refreshing the page, I'm doing:

```
if (gapi.auth2) {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut();
} else {
    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
        gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'myAppID',
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin'
        }).signOut();
    });
}
```

But I get `uncaught exception: This method can only be invoked after the token manager is started` in the else block.

I also have tried to store the auth instance in local storage but doing that led to some cyclic object value errors while stringifying it.

One posible solution is to do a

```
document.location.href = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=myUrl";
```

but, instead of logging the user out only of my application, that would affect all Google's services in which he is logged, besides doing an unwanted redirection.

Is there a different approach?

Comment: Similar question: [How to Logout of an Application Where I Used OAuth2 To Login With Google?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909332/how-to-logout-of-an-application-where-i-used-oauth2-to-login-with-google)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of retrieving the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and setting up the client in my sign-in page controller, I had to initialize it in the index.html file:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js?onload=start" async defer></script>
<script>
    function start() {
      gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'myAppID',
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin'
        });
      });
    }
</script>
```

That solved the logout problem. However, if the sign-in page was refreshed, its controller logic would be executed before the `gapi.auth2` was defined and it wouldn't be posible to successfully attach the click handler to the sign-in button.

In order to avoid that - though not being an elegant solution -, I used [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) to wait until `gapi.auth2` was initialized:

```
waitForAuth2Initialization = $interval(function () {
    console.log("Checking...");
    if (!gapi.auth2)
        return;
    console.log("Ok, gapi.auth2 is not undefined anymore");
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    // Attach signin
    auth2.attachClickHandler...

    $interval.cancel(waitForAuth2Initialization);
}, 50);
```

---

**EDIT:** another possible solution is to use a promise callback for the controller logic to wait until the promise is resolved i.e. until Google API is fully loaded and `gapi.auth2` is ready to use.
It is posible to achieve that by doing:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js?onload=start" async defer></script>
<script>
    gapiPromise = (function () {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        window.start = function () {
            deferred.resolve(gapi);
        };
        return deferred.promise();
    }());
    auth2Promise = gapiPromise.then(function () {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        gapi.load('auth2', function () {
            auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: 'myAppID',
                cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin'
            }).then(function () { 
                deferred.resolve(gapi.auth2); 
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    });
</script>
```

And then in the controller:

```
auth2Promise.then(function () {
    console.log("Ok, gapi.auth2 is not undefined anymore");
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    // Attach signin
    auth2.attachClickHandler...
});
```

But, the downside of this approach is that it is slower (taking twice as much time for the click handler to be attached) than the first one using `$interval`.

Answer (score 8):

there is a easier way, you just have to call .then after calling gapi.auth2.init

```
gapi.load('auth2', function () {
   var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
       client_id: 'myAppID',
       cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin'
   });
   auth2.then(function(){
        // this get called right after token manager is started
        auth2.signOut();
   });
});
```