# Google OAuth2.0 logout not working on localhost but working in console

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

I am using `Google Auth Login` for my application. My `SignIn` button is on the login page and my logout is a part of my header which is included throughout my application. On clicking on logout button I am not being able to sign the user out of my application

Login.tpl code (Which contains sign in button)

```
<div align="middle" class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="CLIENT_ID">
```

I am able to login but not being able to logout.Logout button is a part of the header.tpl which is included in all the files but I am getting the error marked in bold above.

Header.tpl code

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="CLIENT_ID">

<a href="/users/auth/login" class = "logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i> Log Out</a>
```

My JS code

```
    $(".logout").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
gapi.load('auth2', function () {
       var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
           client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
           cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin'
       });
       auth2.then(function(){
            // this get called right after token manager is started
            auth2.signOut();
            console.log('User signed out.');
       });
    });
window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

The code is never entering the block in which signout is defined and hence I am not getting anything in the console as well.

However if I run this code in console, the user gets logged out successfully but this isn't working on the application when I am running it on localhost

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sign out a user after page refresh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35118433/how-to-sign-out-a-user-after-page-refresh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it seems that you can only call signOut method after the signinCallback has fired. So far as I can tell, the only way to fire the signinCallback is to put a sign-in button on the page.

Keeping a hidden sign-in button where my logout button is written did the trick for me.

Included this in header.tpl where my logout button is written

```
    <div style = "display:none" align="middle" class="g-signin2" data-cookiepolicy='single_host_origin' data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work on localhost with the following code:

```
auth2.signOut().then(function () {
   auth2.disconnect();
   gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().reloadAuthResponse();
});
```

Check out the discussion on [this github page](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/232)