# How to ask for new user credentials - Ionic & Firebase

Tags: facebook, oauth, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am currently using AngularFire's `$authWithOAuthPopup` method. On Logout, the Firebase session is ended, but the OAuth persists (as per intended functionality). [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-angular/yt8kzTEhLY8/nB3FJdDl1r0J) 
[Link Explaining oAuth is separate workflow from app logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909332/how-to-logout-of-an-application-where-i-used-oauth2-to-login-with-google)

However, if this happens, the `$authWithOAuthPopup` does not allow for another user to input credentials on re-login.

Have people found success in implementing a solution which allows for someone else to login? How would someone allow for a new user to input new login credentials as opposed to automatically using the old information?

Current behavior: Log user out > click login > app uses previous FB session's information to login.
Wanted behavior: Log user out > click login > asks for user's FB credentials > login.

```
$scope.logout = function () {
  delete $localStorage.storageAuth;
  Auth.$unauth();
  $state.go('user.signin');
};
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You would have to sign the user out off Facebook to accomplish that. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/nOQW82_c9sQ/cLfb3-3FAAAJ

Comment: See the answer i provided for you in the ionic forums https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/facebook-logout-with-firebase-ionic-clear-oauth-session-so-new-user-can-login/54557

Comment: Frank, so is that to say that all Cordova framework apps do not allow for users to log out, and have a new user input? That seems like such a sub-par solution... Are you aware of how I could accomplish this even though it'd be a crappy work flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

original answer in ionic forum https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/facebook-logout-with-firebase-ionic-clear-oauth-session-so-new-user-can-login/54557/2?u=aaronksaunders

can we see the login/auth code... what are you doing with$localStorage.storageAuth you really shouldn't need it for firebase since it will manage the the user's login state for you... I believe...

```
but you can try and clear the cookies/session information

// _blank loads in background, might need clearsessioncache
var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no,clearcache=yes');

// attach a listener to the window which closes it when complete
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { 
    ref.close();
});
```

See documentation https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser1

Answer (score 0):

On behalf of Aaron Saunder's comment above, by clearing the application cache, we are able to prompt for new user information (on Android Marshmellow API > 23 at least). I haven't confirmed on iPhone.

During development on the web browser, it does not exhibit this behavior however, so I guess further testing will be required to see when this is acceptable.

Uses ngCordova `$cordovaInAppBrowser`:

```
$scope.logout = function () {
    var options = {
      location: 'yes',
      clearcache: 'yes',
      toolbar: 'no',
      hidden: 'yes'
    };

    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event){
      $cordovaInAppBrowser.close();
    });
    $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', options);

    Auth.$unauth();
    $state.go('user.signin');
};
```