# Listening to oauth sign outs Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I'm having trouble signing users out from Firebase (not manually).

The app requires `$signInWithPopup` to use it, and whenever user signs out of their google account, I need the firebase to log them out as well. I thought AngularFire's `Auth.$onAuthStateChanged` was handling that but turns out I was wrong when I just tested it.

Is there a listener for this or I'm just missing something here?
BTW I'm limited on server-side though as everything's coded on client-side, so I can't do a server-check to force an unauth()/$signOut().

If there's no such listener then how do we proceed? Do I have to enforce a manual `$timeout` or do oauth resolve on every `$stateChangeStart`?
As I'm typing this, I think it's best to approach this with google sign-in callbacks and do Firebase unauth()/$signout().
Let me know if I'm missing something anyways. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your app is your app, not Google.

The question is really just about OAuth and the way it works. So I found great answer for you. 
[Answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12909563/4698611) In brief: you can't, once you log-in Google side is no longer in talk.