# AWS Cognito - How to force select account when signing in with Google

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, google-oauth

I'm currently using Cognito User Pools, federated with Google as an identity provider, to handle user sign in for my web app. At the moment, I have only implemented Sign-In with Google. This is currently being done through Cognito's Hosted UI.

When users sign in with Google, I'd like them to always be prompted to select their account, i.e. be presented with [this prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTQ8n.png).

However, I have found that when I'm logged in with only one Google account, then this screen is skipped. Although, when I'm logged into no Google account / 2 or more Google accounts, this screen is shown.

Things I've tried to make this screen always show up:

1. Using AWS Amplify's `federatedSignIn({provider: 'Google'})` function. However, I found that this is just a wrapper on Cognito's Hosted UI and just redirects to the same authorization endpoint, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html).
2. Adding `prompt=select_account` to the authorization endpoint as detailed in [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#authenticationuriparameters), however this had no effect. This was unsurprising as the `prompt` option is not detailed in the [AWS documentation for the authorization endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html).

If anyone has any ideas on how I can always have this account selection screen shown, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: did you find answer? Help me with this.

Comment: Have you found the answer to this? Also running into the same issue.

Comment: It is not currently supported by AWS Cognito. Via a support ticket, they did escalate this to their product development team to look into implementing support, but I have not heard back from them regarding a timeframe.

Comment: Any good news ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Turns out that at this moment (January 2020) (edit: see below for their proposed solution which is still problematic) AWS Cognito does not support the `prompt=select_account` (or any of the `prompt` options Google provides). Went back and forth with their support, and here is the final resulting message with their current plan of action:

> (restating the issue) Auth.signOut() only signs out from Cognito, but not from the federated provider (Google in your case). So when you try to login again (in your customers case, using `Auth.federatedSignIn({ .provider: 'Google' }))` it will automatically bypass Google's account selection/login and directly use the existing session. *[which could be a problem if it is the wrong Google session]*
>
> One sub optimal solution to this is to also sign out from Google. You can accomplish this by making a GET request to https://accounts.google.com/logout. This way, a subsequent `federatedSignIn` will need to go through the Google login screen.
>
> I have escalated this case to the Cognito service team in Seattle to get a feature request:
>
> Being able to pass a `prompt="select_account"` option via the URL query to Google.

Edit to add Cognito Response:

> If you're using Cognito Hosted UI, you can clean up the Cognito user pool session by invoking the Logout end point:

```
    https://<Your-User-Pool-Domain>.auth.<Your-User-Pool-Region>.amazoncognito.com/logout?client_id=<Your-User-Pool-App-Client>&logout_uri=<Your-User-Pool-SignOut-URL>
```

> When I (AWS Congito) tried to reproduce the issue with Cognito Hosted UI, I had to re-sign in with Google after I signed out. I couldn't reproduce this issue one way or another.

> See the [Cognito documentation for the logout link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html) for more information and various options.

After trying their response: Unfortunately, this fix (using the logout link) does not work as expected. It DOES let the user select a new identity provider (Google, Facebook, etc.), but if the user is logged in with the one they select, it then proceeds to use that user identity rather than giving the user the option to choose among multiple accounts or login with a new one.

Comment: I thought I was going crazy for a while. Thank you for restoring my sanity. Is the "ticket" publicly viewable? Could you share the link?

Comment: The ticket is not public, but I have shared their response on how to clean up a Cognito session. We haven't had a chance to implement it yet, which is why I hadn't edited this yet.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Have you ever managed to get this fixed?!

Comment: @AhmedFathy We've basically hacked around the issue. We were using the Logout and Relogin link that Cognito has but that causes a different problem. So we now open the Logout link, wait for that to complete, and then open the Login link to the appropriate provider. It doesn't specifically solve the "logged into a single Google account" issue, but it helps ensure the Cognito session is not part of the problem.

Comment: With some digging, I found that upon federated login, a Cognito cookie is stored on the hosted UI domain. When that cookie is manually cleared in the browser, you're able to pick a different account again. However, the only way to clear it is using the LOGOUT endpoint. This means there's no other way to clear it other than to show the hosted UI in your browser. The cookie resides in your provided hosted UI subdomain and cannot be cleared by other subdomains.

Comment: Any solution to this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

The way around this is to use Google as an `OpenID authentication provider` for your user pool in Cognito.

**First, configure Google as a federated Identity provider for AWS**.

Most tutorials for adding Google as a federated identity provider will take you through the initial steps. You can refer to this [medium article](https://ryandam9.medium.com/using-google-as-an-identity-provider-in-aws-cognito-acddfb58fad) or this [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-google-social-identity-provider/) to set up Google as a federated identity provider in AWS. This [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1P_glQGvfo) video explains the steps for that as well.

The most important thing is that you get the `app client Id` and secret from the google console.

**Next you need to configure Google as an `OpenID connect provider` in the AWS IAM service.**

1. In AWS service, Go to the IAM console.
2. Choose "Identity providers" from the navigation menu.
3. Click the "Create provider" button.
4. Choose "OpenID Connect" as the provider type.
5. In the provider URL write `https://accounts.google.com`
6. In the "audience", enter the `client ID` obtained from `Google developer console` for your app.

**Finally set up google as an openID authentication provider for your user pool.**

1. In the AWS console, search for cognito service.
2. Choose "Federated Identities" from the navigation menu.
3. Choose the identity you want to configure or create a new one.
4. Click "edit Identity pool"
5. Under Authentication providers, choose `OpenId`
6. Enable Google as an identity provider.
7. After configuring save your changes.

I am using react for my project. Make sure to add the identity_pool_id of your user pool in your [AWS configuration object](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/client-configuration/configuring-amplify-categories/q/platform/js/#top-level-configuration) on the front end.

Here is the code written in react for your sign in page. You can customize the UI to your liking. Refer to [google identity documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#select_by) on how to configure the UI and authentication flow.

```
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import {useEffect} from "react";

const SignInPage = ()=> {

useEffect(()=>{

//TODO: You can check using Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() to navigate to another page if a user is already logged in

 if (!window.google) createGoogleScript();
},[]);

return (
<>
<form>
{/* google will render its sign-in button in this div below */}
  <div id="buttonDiv"> google div</div>

{ /*you can have a form here for signing in the user with email and password */}

</form>
</>

)

}

const decodeJWTResponse = (jwtToken) => {
  return jwt.decode(jwtToken);
};

const getAWSCredentials = async (googleResponse) => {
  const googleUser = decodeJWTResponse(googleResponse.credential);

  let user = {
    email: googleUser.email,
    name: googleUser.name,
  };

  try {
    const credentials = await Auth.federatedSignIn("google", { token: googleResponse.credential, expires_at: googleUser.exp }, user);
    console.log("credentials from federated sign in ", JSON.stringify(credentials));
//TODO: You can navigate away if you want to, user object will now be available on Auth library
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err);
  }
};


const createGoogleScript = () => {
  // load the Google SDK
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
  script.async = true;
  script.onload = function () {
    window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID_IN_GOOGLE_CONSOLE,
      callback: (result) => {
       getAWSCredentials(result);
      },
    });
    window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
      document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
      { theme: "outline", size: "large" } // customization attributes
    );
    window.google.accounts.id.prompt();
  };
  document.body.appendChild(script);
};
```

[image: Your UI will look this after, allowing you to sign in with different google accounts]

Please note that the User object returned from cognito library with this setup is slightly different from the one you get through the regular sign-in methods so you may have to re-write some of the logic to extract the user information and tokens.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with signing in using Google has been resolved. Now, the prompt is displayed every time to select the Gmail account. This was resolved by calling the URL https://you_cognito_domain/logout?client_id=your_client_id&logout_uri=your_logout_url

front end team has to redirect them by calling this url after cicking on logout

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Exactly, I'm trying to cover this scenario with our own UI, so by communicating with API, but apart from the `GlobalSignOut` I don't see any other options. I'm trying to find information about this in Cognito in general regarding this issue, but so far unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for this issue will be to use the Cognito [Logout and Prompt the User to Sign In As Another User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html#:%7E:text=Logout%20and%20Prompt%20the%20User%20to%20Sign%20In%20As%20Another%20User) instead of calling the normal login. This works similar to the login, but clears any existing session and shows the login screen.
So instead of calling

```
https://xxxxxxxxxxx.auth.xxxxxxx.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&response_type=code&scope=email+openid+profile&redirect_uri=https://example.com/login
```

for login, use this:

```
https://xxxxxxxxxxx.auth.xxxxxxx.amazoncognito.com/logout?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://example.com/login
```

Comment: This was noted in the answer I supplied, with the caveat that it doesn't fully work to resolve the issue.  -- "Unfortunately, this fix (using the logout link) does not work as expected. It DOES let the user select a new identity provider (Google, Facebook, etc.), but if the user is logged in with the one they select, it then proceeds to use that user identity rather than giving the user the option to choose among multiple accounts or login with a new one."

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that happens upon this and needs a simple workaround for development, this solution has allowed me to select other google accounts when logging in again after signing out.

The short of it:

1. In the android emulator/on the android device, log into multiple accounts on the default browser (in my case - and default case - chrome).
2. In the pubspec.yaml, use the preview packages:

   ```yaml
   dependencies:
     amplify_flutter: 1.0.0-next.0
     amplify_auth_cognito: 1.0.0-next.0
   ```
3. Perform your login and logout and you should be prompted to select one of the google accounts on each login.

Source here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/1528#issuecomment-1205936858

Comment: What about the users of the app?
Correct me if I'm wrong, but should one tell them to do that workaround too? 
It's not practical if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I did this for now. When user clicks "logout" in my platform, there will be a new small window and it will automatically close after 1 sec. That small window sends a GET request to google.com

```js
  signOut: async () => {
    const user = get().user;
    if (user?.getUsername().includes("google")) {
      const win = window.open(
        "https://accounts.google.com/logout",
        "_blank",
        "width=600,height=400"
      );
      if (win) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          win.close();
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
    await Auth.signOut();
  },
```

Answer (score -2):

According to the Google documentation, `prompt=consent` requests re-authorization of all scopes that might have been previously granted, and therefore should be used only when necessary (perhaps when migrating user data).

Otherwise, if a user is already signed in to their Google account, this is expected OAuth2.0 behavior. This is the same behavior as using Github for Oauth2.0 authentication with StackOverflow. This thread might shed more light, even if it entails signing out rather than signing in: [How to Logout of an Application Where I Used OAuth2 To Login With Google?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909332/how-to-logout-of-an-application-where-i-used-oauth2-to-login-with-google/12909563#12909563).

Of course, your application should **not** sign users out of their Google accounts from *your* application. You may find yourself with a lot of angry users when they learn that they need to sign back into Google over and over again each time they sign out of your application.

I had a similar situation where users signing out of their Google accounts would **not** prompt an account selection from my application (bypassing the HostedUI). Upgrading `aws-amplify-react` to version 3.1.5 seems to have fixed it, probably due to the `Authenticator` component we're using. I haven't been able to dig into the source code to find what might have been the relevant change, however.

Comment: I don't believe this is relevant, as the problem is with Cognito and not Google OAuth specifically.