# Google federated sign-in with Cognito User Pool and bypassing Hosted UI seems to retain some state on sign out

Tags: authentication, oauth, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I currently have an AWS Amplify app (modified to work with Serverless) configured to allow third-party federation with a Cognito User Pool. Because the Cognito Hosted UI's styling can't be fully customized, I've taken to bypassing it by signing in (and signing out) like so:

```js
Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: 'Google' })

Auth.signOut()
```

When signing in, my app is able to successfully request authentication with Google, and I am prompted for my email and password. This also signs me into my Google account, which I believe is common in an OAuth 2.0 authentication flow.

The issue arises when I sign out of my Google account *and* my app. Upon doing so and signing into my app again, I am logged in automatically. Interestingly, I am **not** logged into my Google account again. It's as if my app skips the step to authenticate against Google. This still happens when I clear cookies, local storage, and restart my browser.

Surprisingly, using the Hosted UI doesn't suffer from this problem. Logging out of Google and then logging into my app requires re-authentication every time.

I am otherwise unable to figure out how my browser (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) is able to "remember" who I am as a Google user when logging into my app. Like I mentioned, I tried clearing cookies and local data, and restarting my browser. This isn't an issue in Incognito mode. I tried looking through the [source code](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/auth/src/Auth.ts) to see where some data might be set in storage, but Amplify mostly seems to rely on local storage by default, which gets cleared on sign out.

I am wondering if anyone else bypassing the Hosted UI has seen this behavior, or if there is some specific, high-level Amplify configuration I may have made a mistake with?

Comment: You haven't made any mistakes. This question explains what's going on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154256/aws-cognito-how-to-force-select-account-when-signing-in-with-google/59580105

Comment: @teddybeard Thanks for replying. I did find a solution to my particular issue, which was to upgrade `aws-amplify-react` from version 2.3.10 to version 3.1.5. With this upgrade, if a user is signed out from their Google account, my app seeks re-authentication/account selection every single time.