# Aws Cognito sign-out and session clear not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I have integrated **Aws Congnito** federated authentication with provider in react native, it is working good.

**Issue is:**

> When i m going to logout and login again it is not asking my login
> account account details again, it takes directly old account and logged.

i tried these line of code while logout for session clear:

```
 Auth.signOut();

cognitoCredentials.clearCachedId();
cognitoCredentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(cognitoParams);
AWS.config.credentials = cognitoCredentials
```

then i used amplity Hub listen , events are triggerd good

```
 Hub.listen("auth", ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
    switch (event) {
      case "signIn":
      case 'cognitoHostedUI':
        break;
       case "signOut":
          console.log('Yes Logout');
         //clear my local 
          break;
        case 'signIn_failure':
        case 'cognitoHostedUI_failure':
          console.log('Sign in failure', data);
          break;
        case "customOAuthState":
  });
```

i noticed this one but i can't solve my problem
[How to force select account when signing in with Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154256/aws-cognito-how-to-force-select-account-when-signing-in-with-google).

I would like to know if anything i missed , please provide any solution to me.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue and cant figure out how to clear the seasion completely.