# AWS cognito signout from google account not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I'm facing a problem with aws cognito login. When I'm logging in with google, it is fine. but when I'm logging out and again clicking on "sign in with google" button it is taking me to the previous account that I logged in before logging out without asking me to select an account. But when I clear the cookies clicking on the "View site information" button on the address bar(Cannot find anything in Application=>cookies storage, that's why I had to use this method) and log out, and again try to login with google then it is asking me to select a google account to log in. But without clearing cookies from view site information it is taking me to previous account without giving me list of account to log in.

See this image that may help you to understand better:
[image]

Here is my logOut function:

```
const logout = () => {
    window.location.reload();
    const user = Pool.getCurrentUser();
    if (user) {
      user.signOut();
    }
    const accessToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));
    const refreshToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("refreshToken"));

    if (accessToken) {
      localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
    }
    if (refreshToken) {
      localStorage.removeItem("refreshToken");
    }
    const authUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authUser"));
    if (authUser) {
      localStorage.removeItem("authUser");
    }
    navigate(RoutingPaths.Login);
  };
```

authenticate function:

```
const authenticate = (Username, Password) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const user = new CognitoUser({
        Username,
        Pool: Pool,
      });

      const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
        Username,
        Password,
      });
      user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
        onSuccess: (data) => {
          resolve(data);
        },
        onFailure: (err) => {
          reject(err);
        },
        newPasswordRequired: (data) => {
          resolve(data);
        },
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Cognito - How to force select account when signing in with Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154256/aws-cognito-how-to-force-select-account-when-signing-in-with-google)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's anything wrong that you do with the logout on your part. Most probably it's Amazon Cognito remembering the preferred user and trying to log in with that user. If your Google session for that user was expired, I'm pretty sure that you would have seen that "choose account" screen again.

When you clear cookies through that "i" icon in the browser, you also clear Cognito's cookies. That's why it forgets the preferred Google user and asks to choose the account again. You don't see those cookies in the Application -> cookie storage, because the browser only shows localhost cookies there.

Comment: Thanks for making it more clear. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: I don't think it's an issue. Maybe there is something in the SDK that will allow you to clear that cookie. You would have to check Cognito's docs.