# Cannot Logout from Google account in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-cognito, googlesigninaccount

I am using AWS Cognito to login using Google in my React project. Before I just was saving the user information in localStorage when signed In using email and password.

I got the following function for Google login button in react:

```
const signUpWithGoogle = () => {
    const cognitoDomain = "cognito domain"; // Example: 'myapp.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com'
    const responseType = "code"; // or 'code' if you've setup code grant
    const clientId = "CLIENT_ID";
    const redirectUri = encodeURIComponent("http://localhost:3000/"); // Example: 'https://www.myapp.com/callback'
    // const redirectUri = encodeURIComponent("REDIRECT_URL"); // Example: 'https://www.myapp.com/callback'
    const identityProvider = "Google";

    const signUpUrl = `https://cognito_domain/oauth2/authorize?identity_provider=${identityProvider}&response_type=${responseType}&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&`;

    window.location.href = signUpUrl;
  };
```

After the pressed then I am redirected to the specified page with a code as a url parameter.
Then I get The code and login via this code:

```
 if (code) {
    try {
      const poolData = {
        UserPoolId: "UserPoolId",
        ClientId: "ClientId",
      };

      const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
      const url = `https://oddsview.auth.us-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=ClientId&code=${code}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/`;
      

      fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          const idToken = data.id_token;
          try {
            const decodedToken = jwtDecode(idToken);
            console.log(idToken);
            console.log(decodedToken.sub);
           //Do more stuff with it.
          } catch (err) {}
          // console.log(decodedToken);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log( error);
    }
  }
```

Now the problem I am facing is I cannot get any solution how to logout the user. I see in my localhost cookie some sessions like `cognito`and other cookies, when I delete the cookies manually  then after clicking the button I get the select account google page.

But otherwise when I click the google login button I do not get the Google select account page rather it returns to my redirect url as the user logged in.

I want to logout the google or anyother method so that at least if I click the login button it gives me the select account page.

Comment: Are you using Amplify libraries?

Comment: No I am only using  `"amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.3.5"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Cognito - How to force select account when signing in with Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154256/aws-cognito-how-to-force-select-account-when-signing-in-with-google)