# Sign in with with Google in AWS Cognito without Hosted UI

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, google-signin, aws-amplify

I'm currently trying to use `@react-native-google-signin` library in my React Native project to log in a user in my app and then authenticate him on my cognito user pool using was-amplify. So basically without using the hosted UI

Currently, I have this in my app:

```js
function GoogleSignInButton() {

  const handleGoogleSignIn = async () => {
    const {idToken, user} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    const jwtClaims = parseJwt(idToken);
    
    const googleCredentials = await Auth.federatedSignIn('google', { token: idToken, expires_at: jwtClaims.exp }, user);
  };

  render(
    <Button title={'Google Sign In'} onPress={handleGoogleSignIn}/>
  );
}
```

The GoogleSignIn part works perfectly and returns correctly both the idToken and the user properties.

However, when I call the Auth.federatedSignIn(...) returned me the error:

> NotAuthorizedException: Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool.

I'm pretty sure I configured correctly the AWS Cognito user pool, since if I access the hosted UI I can successfully log in and register a user

I configured google as a federated identity provider in my user pool

[image]

I also saw some confusing documentation that led me to add the google identity provider to the identity pool linked to my user pool, like this:

[image]

However, I then received this error:

> InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException: Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool.

Which lead me to believe that this is probably not the right direction.

So going to the original issue: how is it possible that it's not realizing that the token comes from google which is the specified identity provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried this solution and got the same results as you. I recommend to watch this video [Lesson 4.1 OAuth and React Native (Google Login)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYUFJRzS8Cg). From what I understood we need to use `Identity pools` from the left side menu. This can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/75291833/10617148

[image: AWS Console]

---

Also, I tried another solution [React Native App Auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/blob/main/docs/config-examples/aws-cognito.md) with the same results.

Comment: After adding changes on the backend I got good results for React Native App Auth https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/blob/main/docs/config-examples/aws-cognito.md