# Log out of Google Oauth in webapp from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, google-oauth

When the user authenticateswith the "sign in" with google button with javascript the user is redirected into my webapp basedon the successful return. I pass the id-token to the backend and use `$client->verifyIdToken($id_token);` to fetch and can get the userid ('sub'). Great!

When the user wants to logout, I need to kill the session on the backend so I have a page /logout that logs the user out and then redirects to the top page. However, the top page javascript login box still indicates that the user is signed in and triggers a sign in and gets redirected back into the webapp which is bad. If the user has logged out, I want them to have to click the Google "Sign in" button again and have it run automatically.

I've looked through all the documentation I can find for the PHP backend and I can't seem to find any way to log the user out of my app. I've even tried calling `$client->revokeToken();` on the backend on the logout page but it has no effect.

Is there anyway to logout the Google user from my app on the backend or am I forced to detect if the user is logged in, call this javascript first and then proceed to my logout page?

```
<script>
  function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
      console.log('User signed out.');
    });
  }
</script>
```

It would seem to me that there should be a logout from google (or revoke the current session in webapp (token?) ) from the backend but I can't find it for the life of me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Logout of an Application Where I Used OAuth2 To Login With Google?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909332/how-to-logout-of-an-application-where-i-used-oauth2-to-login-with-google)

Answer (score 0):

Google does not allow for third party logout.  That being said your application can not log a user out of Google.  If they allowed that then your app could also log me out of Stack overflow and every other third party website that i have logged in using my Google account.

What you need to do is remove the login to your own site by removing the cookie that was probably set somewhere.

Comment: As I noted in question, I'm not looking to logout the user from google but stop the Google signin button automatically logging in the user on my website (I wanted the user to have to click the "sign in" button again